# Name of the template from which the extension is generated?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In **Hybris**, how to find the template from which an extension is generated? Any solution would be great.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: OOTB you can't be 100% sure to know the template, you can have almost empty templates for example. The only solution is see would be to add an ant task in buildcallback to be run after the extension generation that will set in a file the name of the template. For hybris template this solution is not valid although. It's not really an interesting feature you should not expect to have this information automatically imho. You know the template used when you do the generation, it's up to you to maintain a documentation with this kind of information. I think it's just simpler to do it this way.

Comment: Why would you need to know ?